# Get duplicates from one table for records from another

Tags: c#, postgresql

I've got three tables:

Table1:

```
id | name         
-------------------
1  | ExampleName1  
2  | ExampleName2 
3  | ExampleName 
4  | Example2Name 
5  | ExampleNamee
```

Table2:

```
id  | text          | idTable1
-------------------------------
20  | ExampleText1  | 1
21  | Ext1          | 1
22  | Text1         | 3
22  | pleText1      | 2
```

Table3:

```
id  | login      | idTable1
----------------------------
20  | EEEEEEEE   | 1
5   | WWWWWWWWw  | 2
6   | QQQQQQQQQQ | 1
10  | TTTTTTTT   | 1
11  | OOOOOOOOO  | 2
```

And I would like to get all records from Table2 but if in table3 there are several records for a given table1ID I would like the data from table2 will be duplicated

example:
Result from table2 where idTable1 = 1:

```
id | text           | idTable1 | Table3Login
---------------------------------------------
20 | ExampleText1   | 1        | EEEEEEEE   
20 | ExampleText1   | 1        | QQQQQQQQQQ 
20 | ExampleText1   | 1        | TTTTTTTT   
21 | Ext1           | 1        | EEEEEEEE 
21 | Ext1           | 1        | QQQQQQQQQQ 
21 | Ext1           | 1        | TTTTTTTT
```

What type join to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `JOIN` of your tables as follows:

> Query:
>
> ```
> SELECT T2.id, T2.text, T2.idTable1, T3.login AS Table3Login
> FROM Table1 AS T1 JOIN Table2 AS T2 
> ON T1.id = T2.idTable1 JOIN Table3 AS T3 
> ON T2.idTable1 = T3.idTable1 
> ORDER BY T2.text;
> ```

> Results:
>
> ```
> id | text         | idtable1 | table3login
> -: | :----------- | -------: | :----------
> 20 | ExampleText1 |        1 | EEEEEEEE   
> 20 | ExampleText1 |        1 | QQQQQQQQQQ 
> 20 | ExampleText1 |        1 | TTTTTTTT   
> 21 | Ext1         |        1 | EEEEEEEE   
> 21 | Ext1         |        1 | QQQQQQQQQQ 
> 21 | Ext1         |        1 | TTTTTTTT   
> 22 | pleText1     |        2 | WWWWWWWWw  
> 22 | pleText1     |        2 | OOOOOOOOO
> ```

*[Check this dbfiddle working sample here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=419faf2642c13b92505cf6c95f9fd928)*:

---

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1 (
>   id INT NOT NULL, 
>   name VARCHAR(50)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE Table2 (
>   id INT NOT NULL, 
>   text VARCHAR(50),
>   idTable1 INT 
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE  Table3 
> (
>   id INT NOT NULL, 
>   login VARCHAR(50),
>   idTable1 INT 
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> ---- INSERT Table1: 
> INSERT INTO Table1 (id, name)
> SELECT 1, 'ExampleName1';  
>
> INSERT INTO Table1 (id, name)
> SELECT 2, 'ExampleName2';  
>
> INSERT INTO Table1 (id, name)
> SELECT 3, 'ExampleName';  
>
> INSERT INTO Table1 (id, name)
> SELECT 4, 'Example2Name';  
>
> INSERT INTO Table1 (id, name)
> SELECT 5, 'ExampleNamee';
>
> ---- INSERT Table2: 
> INSERT INTO Table2 (id, text, idTable1) 
> SELECT 20, 'ExampleText1', 1;
> INSERT INTO Table2 (id, text, idTable1) 
> SELECT 21, 'Ext1', 1;
> INSERT INTO Table2 (id, text, idTable1) 
> SELECT 22, 'Text1', 3;
> INSERT INTO Table2 (id, text, idTable1) 
> SELECT 22, 'pleText1', 2;
>
> ---- INSERT Table3: 
> INSERT INTO Table3 (id, login, idTable1)
> SELECT 20, 'EEEEEEEE', 1;
> INSERT INTO Table3 (id, login, idTable1)
> SELECT 5, 'WWWWWWWWw', 2;
> INSERT INTO Table3 (id, login, idTable1)
> SELECT 6, 'QQQQQQQQQQ', 1;
> INSERT INTO Table3 (id, login, idTable1)
> SELECT 10, 'TTTTTTTT', 1;
> INSERT INTO Table3 (id, login, idTable1)
> SELECT 11, 'OOOOOOOOO', 2;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name        
> -: | :-----------
>  1 | ExampleName1
>  2 | ExampleName2
>  3 | ExampleName 
>  4 | Example2Name
>  5 | ExampleNamee
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Table2;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | text         | idtable1
> -: | :----------- | -------:
> 20 | ExampleText1 |        1
> 21 | Ext1         |        1
> 22 | Text1        |        3
> 22 | pleText1     |        2
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Table3;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | login      | idtable1
> -: | :--------- | -------:
> 20 | EEEEEEEE   |        1
>  5 | WWWWWWWWw  |        2
>  6 | QQQQQQQQQQ |        1
> 10 | TTTTTTTT   |        1
> 11 | OOOOOOOOO  |        2
> ```

> This is the query:

> ```
> -- This is the query: 
> SELECT T2.id, T2.text, T2.idTable1, T3.login AS Table3Login
> FROM Table1 AS T1 JOIN Table2 AS T2 
> ON T1.id = T2.idTable1 JOIN Table3 AS T3 
> ON T2.idTable1 = T3.idTable1 
> ORDER BY T2.text;
> ```

> Results:
>
> ```
> id | text         | idtable1 | table3login
> -: | :----------- | -------: | :----------
> 20 | ExampleText1 |        1 | EEEEEEEE   
> 20 | ExampleText1 |        1 | QQQQQQQQQQ 
> 20 | ExampleText1 |        1 | TTTTTTTT   
> 21 | Ext1         |        1 | EEEEEEEE   
> 21 | Ext1         |        1 | QQQQQQQQQQ 
> 21 | Ext1         |        1 | TTTTTTTT   
> 22 | pleText1     |        2 | WWWWWWWWw  
> 22 | pleText1     |        2 | OOOOOOOOO
> ```